# How do I type hint the user argument when calling passport.serializeUser in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, passport.js

Using TypeScript, I'm writing an API using Express and Mongoose, and I'm trying to set up authentication using Passport, but I'm getting a "Property does not exist" error when trying to pass a serializer function to passport.

According to the [documentation](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/), I need to call `passport.serializeUser` with a function that takes my user object and calls `done` with that user's ID.

I'm getting the type definitions from `@types/passport`, and the [declaration file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/passport/index.d.ts) types the `user` argument for the `serializeUser` function as `Express.User`:

```
serializeUser<TID>(fn: (user: Express.User, done: (err: any, id?: TID) => void) => void): void;
```

But `Express.User` - also defined by `@types/passport` - is an empty interface:

```
declare global {
    namespace Express {
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-empty-interface
        interface AuthInfo {}
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-empty-interface
        interface User {}
```

Here's my serializer. TypeScript complains that `Property '_id' does not exist on type 'User'`.

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user._id);
});
```

To work around this, I've added my type definition that add the `_id` property to Express.User:

```
declare namespace Express {
  interface User {
    _id?: string;
  }
}
```

This eliminates the TypeScript error, but it doesn't seem like this is the correct way to solve the problem. Is there a different way to provide a serializer function that doesn't require me to override the `Express.User` type definition?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way [Declaration Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) you've done is recommended by @types/express contributors.
You can find how they test `serializerUser` with TypeScript [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/passport/passport-tests.ts#L9).

```js
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface User {
      username: string;
      _id?: number;
    }
  }
}
```

Another way is to type `User` argument of callback function each time you use the function:

```js
type User = {
  _id?: number
}

passport.serializeUser((user: User, done) => {
  done(null, user._id);
});
```

I think Declaration Merging is a bit smarter way.